# List \n with f-String format

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook, format, f-string

I know you can't use \n in f string formats{} but I'm trying to figure out how to print a list separated by line.

**Each printed number should have a width of 10**

```
# Output
#         12
#         28
#         45
#         47
#         52
#         71
#         95
#        122
#        164
```

I'm not allowed to use any external modules such as itertools or functools to answer this question.

I've tried

```
num_list = [12, 16, 17, 2, 5, 19, 24, 27, 42]
new_list = num_list.copy()
for n in range(1, len(new_list)):
    new_list[n] += new_list[n-1]

print(f'{*new_list:10f, sep = "\n"}')
```

Comment: are you allowed to loop the iist?

Comment: can you show us a sample list?

Comment: yes we're allowed to loop and just edited the list with a sample list!

Comment: `print('\n'.join([f'{x:10f}' for x in new_list]))` There's no restriction on using `\n` per se, but you confusing the keyword arguments to `print` with the f-string syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will print a line every loop and using .rjust() to add 10 leading spaces.

```
for n in range(1, len(new_list)):
    new_list[n] += new_list[n-1]

for num in new_list:
    print(f"{num}".rjust(10))
```

Comment: It worked but now it's not printing the first number (12)

Output is 
        28
        45
        47
        52
        71
        95
       122
       164

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @chepner!! This worked

```
print('\n'.join([f'{x:10}' for x in new_list]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with the f-string as you were intending, just print it as you go along with the calculation. This also avoids an additional iteration over the list.

```
num_list = [12, 16, 17, 2, 5, 19, 24, 27, 42]
new_list = num_list.copy()

print(f'{new_list[0]:10}') # This gets you the first value

for n in range(1, len(new_list)):
    new_list[n] += new_list[n-1]
    print(f'{new_list[n]:10}') # This prints as you go
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `str.join`:

```
print('\n'.join(f'{n}'.rjust(10) for n in  new_list))
```

or use the built-in function `print` with an unpacked generator expression and the separator set as `\n`:

```
print(*(f'{n}'.rjust(10) for n in  new_list), sep='\n')
```

output:

```
    12
    28
    45
    47
    52
    71
    95
   122
   164
```